Migrate from Nx14 to Nx16, NextJs, TawilwindCSS and typescript
I am trying to migrate my project from Nx14 to Nx16 in order to use Node20.
I made the migration manual from Nx14 to Nx15 and then Nx16 as suggested in Nx docs.
while building the project pass successfully, serving the project fails, when running:nx run-many --projects spacedeck --target serve --parallel,
I get,
Error: Cannot find module 
'/pichu/dist/apps/spacedeck/.next/build-manifest.json'
Require stack:
- /Users/amitay.tsinis/Documents/GitHub/pichu/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js
- /Users/amitay.tsinis/Documents/GitHub/pichu/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js

My assumption is that this issue is related to the next.config.js file, as I didn't find any reference for a config file that suits my requirements. Nx documentation suggests to import withNx from @nx/next, which caused me also issues.
const { withNx } = require('@nrwl/next/plugins/with-nx');
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');

process.env.I18NEXT_DEFAULT_CONFIG_PATH = `${__dirname}/next-i18next.config.js`;
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config');

const nextConfig = {
  transpilePackages: ['monaco-editor'],
  nx: {
    svgr: true,
  },
};

module.exports = withNx({
  i18n,
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      // Transpile specified packages for both client and server environments
      nextConfig.transpilePackages.forEach((packageName) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: new RegExp(
            `[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\]${packageName}[/\\\\].*\\.js$`
          ),
          use: 'next-transpile-modules',
        });
      });
    }

    const rule = config.module.rules
      .find((rule) => rule.oneOf)
      .oneOf.find(
        (r) => r.issuer && r.issuer.include && r.issuer.include.includes('_app')
      );

    if (rule) {
      // Update global CSS loader to include monaco-editor
      rule.issuer.include = [
        rule.issuer.include,
        /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]monaco-editor[\\/]/,
      ];
    }

    config.plugins.push(
      new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
        languages: ['sql'],
        filename: 'static/[name].worker.js',
      })
    );

    return config;
  },
})(nextConfig);

tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.js", "**/*.jsx", "next-env.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "jest.config.ts"]
}

project.json
{
  "name": "spacedeck",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/spacedeck",
  "projectType": "application",
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/next:build",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "defaultConfiguration": "production",
      "options": {
        "root": "apps/spacedeck",
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/spacedeck"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {},
        "development": {
          "outputPath": "tmp/apps/spacedeck"
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/next:server",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "spacedeck:build",
        "dev": true
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "buildTarget": "spacedeck:build:production",
          "dev": false
        },
        "development": {
          "buildTarget": "spacedeck:build:development",
          "dev": true
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },
  "tags": [],
  "implicitDependencies": ["tailwind"]

I have tried to migrate thourgh the manual guide of Nx but, couldn't find a good example of how to setup a correct next.config.js file, which in my opinion causes this error.

It has been some changes in config files throughout Nx major versions, check all of them in root and libs and apps folders. Like root pacakge.json,  root nx.json,  all tsconfig, in every project project.json.
Try to use npx nx migrate latest  (current v19) or to older major versions v16, v17, v18
Check the settings for a NextJS web https://github.com/guillempuche/nx-expo-next-tamagui/tree/main/apps/next
Tailwind shouldn't be the cause of the problem. I recommend you to create a blank new Nx project with Tailwind to check the dependencies versions and settings in the web. Then apply it to your Nx monorepo.
